# Why is Java updating multiple variables with the same value?

Tags: java, class, variables, methods, reference

I have a class called Time that contains objects whose instances have "hour" and "minute" parameters. In that class is a method called addMinutes which takes in an integer and adds that number of minutes to the "hour" and "minute" parameters of the object.

I have a constructor method in another class called Exercise that is supposed to make an object with the following parameters:
String object called extype
int object called min
Time object called start
Time object called end

I want the constructor to initialize start and then use the addMinutes method from Time to add that number of minutes and call that end. But when I use it, the start is updated with the end even if they are separate variables.

Here is the addMinutes method

```
public void addMinutes(int mins) {
   this.mins += mins;
        if (this.mins >= 60) {
            addHours(this.mins / 60);
            this.mins = this.mins % 60;
      }
```

Here's an example of trying to use this and the output

```
    public Exercise(String e, int m, Time s) {
       extype = e;
       min = m;
       start = s;
       System.out.println(start);
       end = s;
       System.out.println(start);
       end.addMinutes(min);
       System.out.print(s);
       start = s;
       System.out.println(start);
```

The output from running this with e = "Dancing", m = 90, and S = 15:45

Exercise e1 = new Exercise("Dancing",90,firsttime);

15:45

15:45

17:15 17:15

So when I use end.addMinutes(min) all the variables, start, end, and even s are updated to what I want to be the end time.  Any insight on this?

Thanks.

Comment: The `=` operator doesn't do what you think it does.  Unless a class explicitly defines it to copy the individual data members, it sets the variables to point to the same object.

Comment: @AdamLiss: You cannot override the = operator in Java.

Comment: Okay, awesome! So that's what I'm doing wrong. Is there any way to make a new object identical to that one without redefining the start parameter?

Answer (score 1):

It is because Java uses references for its objects, not valules

Thus, when you do `start = s` , it doesn't set start to the value of s, but set start to be *the same object* as s. And so on for the other assignement.

Then, when you call a method on any of these (namely : start, end, or s), you call this method on one and only one object, referenced by these three variables.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute `end = s;`, you are setting the object referenced by `end` to the the same one as referenced by `s`.  Therefore, when you change the object, it is reflected in both references.  If you want them to be different, they have to be set to different variables.

Give your class a "clone" method that creates a new object of the same type and sets all internal variables of the new object to those of the old one.  Then clone instead of using '=', and you will have separate objects.

Answer (score 0):

This is because all objects in Java are implicetly by reference.
If you say that end is equal to start, then they both refer to the same object, so updating the one results in updating the other.

What you can do is the following: let addMinutes() return a new Time object with the specified minutes and hours. Then don't state `end=start` but do this:

```
Time end;
end = start.addMinutes(m);
```

this should work.

Good luck!

Comment: The problem with this is that addMinutes has no return. This was my original approach, but of course setting a Time object to a method with void return you will get a compiler error for incompatible types.

Comment: Then either you can create a clone() function witch returns a new Time object with the same fields OR you can change the function signature from public void addMinutes(int mins) to public Time addMinutes(int mins) this allows you to return a new Time

Answer (score 0):

In java, variables that store objects are in fact storing "references" to objects. In other words, if you have the following:

```
Object obj;
cpy = obj;
```

Both `obj` and `copy` will point to the SAME object. If you update EITHER of them, BOTH will be affected.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is Java updating multiple variables with the same value?

It isn't. It is updating a single object, and you have multiple variables that all refer to that object, so whichever variable you use to get a value inside the object, you always get the same value.